# Substitution on string in perl changes string to an integer value

Tags: perl

I am trying to do delete some characters matching a regex in perl and when I do that it returns an integer value.

I have tried substituting multiple spaces in a string with empty string or basically deleting the space.

```
#! /usr/intel/bin/perl

my $line = "foo/\\bar car"; 
print "$line\n";
#$line = ~s/(\\|(\s)+)+//; <--Ultimately need this, where backslash and space needs to be deleted. Tried this, returns integer value
$line = ~s/\s+//; <-- tried this, returns integer value
print "$line\n";
```

Expected results:
First print: `foo/\bar car`
Second print: `foo/barcar`

Actual result:
First print: `foo/\\bar car`
Second print: `18913234908`

Comment: There's a difference between `=~` and `= ~`...

Comment: You should `use warnings;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper solution is

```
$line =~ s/[\s\\]+//g;
```

Note:

- `g` flag to substitute all occurrences
- no space between `=` and `~`

`=~` is a single operator, binding the substitution operator `s` to the target variable `$line`.

Inserting a space (as in your code) means `s` binds to the default target, `$_`, because there is no explicit target, and then the return value (which is the number of substitutions made) has all its bits inverted (unary `~` is bitwise complement) and is assigned to `$line`.

In other words,

```
$line = ~ s/...//
```

parses as

```
$line = ~(s/...//)
```

which is equivalent to

```
$line = ~($_ =~ s/...//)
```

If you had enabled `use warnings`, you would've gotten the following message:

```
Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution (s///) at prog.pl line 6.
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already accepted an answer, but I thought it would be useful to give you a few more details.

As you now know,

```
$line = ~s/\s+//;
```

is completely different to:

```
$line =~ s/\s+//;
```

You wanted the second, but you typed the first. So what did you end up with?

`~` is "bitwise negation operator". That is, it converts its argument to a binary number and then bit-flips that number - all the zeroes become ones and all the ones become zeros.

So you're asking for the bitwise negation of `s/\s+//`. Which means the bitwise negation works on the value returned by `s/\s+//`. And the value returned by a substitution is the number of substitutions made.

We can now work out all of the details.

- `s/\s+//` carries out your substitution and returns the number of substitutions made (an integer).
- `~s/\s+//` returns the bitwise negation of the integer returned by the substitution (which is also an integer).
- `$line = ~s/\s+//` takes that second integer and assigns it to the variable `$line`.

Probably, the first step returns 1 (you don't use `/g` on your `s/.../.../`, so only one substitution will be made). It's easy enough to get the bitwise negation of 1.

```
$ perl -E'say ~1'
18446744073709551614
```

So that might well be the integer that you're seeing (although it might be different on a 32-bit system).